# Why hash of a key is maintained inside a HashMap node?

Tags: java, hash, java-8, hashmap

I wanted to understand why hash (final int hash) of a key is maintained inside linked list node mapped to a HashMap bucket? Once the bucket is identified using hashcode of a key, then key itself could be used to compare the key values present inside the nodes of linked list using equals.

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash; // Why is it here?
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next;
    Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
        this.hash = hash; 
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
```

I know there must be some reason for this. If anybody please help me understand this with an example. Thanks !

Comment: One possible reason is that comparing two hashes with `==` is more efficient than comparing two objects with `equals()`.

Comment: Don't you have to only compare two objects when they resolve to same hash ?

Comment: When expanding the internal array, it’s much cheaper to use the stored hash code instead of recalculating it for every contained key.